# Android get Gravatar image library

Tags: android

in my application i can not use simple code to get user-email gravatar image by :

```
   String gravatarUrl = 
   "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7a90eb07999167d6a44857f5325aea9d?s=204&d=404";
```

user email is not fake address for test my user email is `pishguy@gmail.com` and i can not get image, i'm find some library but dont work correctly, i think new system of gravatar web site is change

please help me or refer new library for this ability

Answer (score 0):

I used gravatar images recently in a project and the code that I use:

```
String hash = MD5Util.md5Hex(email);
            String gravatarUrl = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + hash + "?s=204&d=404";

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(gravatarUrl)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar_empty)
                .into(holder.userImageView);
```

You can check it on [gitHub](https://github.com/Iregar/YepApplication) on UserAdapter class.
You can find more information about gravatar uses in the site of [gravatar](https://es.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/java/).

Comment: dont wok sir. Picasso only view image defined with placeholder, can you test my email and my avatar?

Comment: I tested your email and your hash and all is ok but I think that your gravatar do not have an image linked or your hash is not ok.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code i used.
get library from:-   https://github.com/tkeunebr/gravatar-android  (you will get the .jar,,  add it to lib)

### Code for loading gravatar:

```
String gravatarUrl = Gravatar.init().with(user.email).size(100).build();
Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(gravatarUrl)
       .into((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_avatar));
```

And if you want to set a default image in case of there is no gravatar set for the email(to override the default gravatar) then use:

```
String gravatarUrl = Gravatar.init().with(user.email).defaultImage(defaultImageUrl).size(100).build();
```

Hope this helps someone.